# no such element: Unable to locate element:while web scraping Youtube comments

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Iam trying to get the youtube comments using selenium but iam getting error.Can anyone please help mee with this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNltVQqJhRE")
time.sleep(10)
D=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//yt-formatted-string[@id="content-text"]')
print(D.text)
```

Iam getting this

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//yt-formatted-string[@id="content-text"]"}
```

It works with this code.But its not scraping all the comments.This code I found in stack overflow.

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFPMz36std4')

driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(1, 500);')

#now wait let load the comments
time.sleep(5)

driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(1, 3000);')



comment_div=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contents"]')
comments=comment_div.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-text"]')
for comment in comments:
    print(comment.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that that ID doesn't exist (at least not for me). Find an ID that does. If you are using chrome, just right click on the element (after inspecting), and then copy xpath to get the xpath of an element.

Comment: Use `.find_element_by_id('content-text')` then, and see if you get anything. If it works, it is a problem with the class name, otherwise, with the id

Comment: @ ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000..Iam getting this D=find_element_by_id('content-text')
NameError: name 'find_element_by_id' is not defined

Comment: driver.find_element_by_id('content-text')

Comment: @ ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 Its still showing same error.I have included another code that works but i dont know how it work.Its not showing all the comments.

Comment: Which error are you talking about? NameError or NoSuchElementException

Comment: It shows no such elements. This guy gave the solution**Oluwafemi Sule**

Answer (score 0):

The browser needs to wait until the document is ready. A sweet time spot is about 4500ms. You can then scroll the comments section into view and wait for it to roll in for about 3000ms. After this, `#context-text` will be sitting right there in the DOM.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNltVQqJhRE"
driver.get(url)

wait(driver, 4500)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight + 500);")
driver.implicitly_wait(3000)

content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//yt-formatted-string[@id="content-text"]')                                          

print(content.text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.It works.Can you say what this line does**driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight + 500);")**

Comment: It scrolls the comment section into view. Mostly the first part

Comment: Thanks a lot.It gave me head ache for a day.

Comment: Iam sry but its loading the first part of comment section as u said.How to  get the all comments on that page